# Game Programming - & Logical Operator and .getRGB() Method

Tags: java

I have two question pertaining to the code below:

```
pixels = image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, null, 0, width);

for(int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++)
{
    pixels[i] = (pixels[i] & 0xff) / 64;
}
```

My first question is what does the last argument, which is set as width, do in the `.getRGB` method. The second is what does `(pixels[i] & 0xff) / 64` do, since I have never encountered the `&` operator nor do I know what `0xff` means, I assume, however, that it has something to do with altering the RGB value. This is for a 2D game, I am trying to make, as per a book I am currently reading.

Here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/fPjvrFWG

Thank you!

Comment: what particular class is `image` an instance of?

Comment: Done. Sorry, for it being vague.

Comment: BufferedImage, is what image is an instance of.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/fPjvrFWG, here is the full code.

Comment: what is `image`? [`java.awt.Image`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html) doesn't have a `getRGB` method.

Comment: as for the second half - check any java tutorial that mentions bitwise operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the final `scansize` parameter, see the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int[],%20int,%20int)):

> With a specified coordinate (x, y) in the image, the ARGB pixel can be accessed in this way:
>
> `pixel = rgbArray[offset + (y-startY)*scansize + (x-startX)];`

The intent of this is to allow your destination array to have a width that is different from the portion that is being extracted.

The `& 0xff` operator is extracting just the blue component of the ARGB pixel value, since the bits in the pixel are arranged thus:

```
AAAAAAAA RRRRRRRR GGGGGGGG BBBBBBBB
```

So "anding" with `0xff` produces:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 BBBBBBBB
```

Then, the division by 64 is throwing away all but the two most significant bits of that blue value, i.e. 0 - 63 becomes 0, 64 - 127 becomes 1, 128 - 191 becomes 2, and 192 - 255 becomes 3.

Comment: Could you maybe give me an example about how this would work? I don't really understand. I get that my integer has 4 parts ARGB, but why would doing 0xff, return only B. The division by 64 I get now though. So, I suppose my new questions are why does the book only return the B? What connotations does that have? And also, how does doing 0xff return only the B, because from my knowledge the & operator does something like this: 000111 & 011101 = 000101

Comment: Ok, so I think what is happening is the code is trying to make the image monochromatic then add in color later, in order to make it run better, so if that is correct, please correct me if it is not, then the main thing I want to know is how exactly 0xff extracts the B portion.

Comment: I've added an explanation of how it's just the B value getting extracted, but I cannot offer you an explanation as to _why_, since that depends on the semantics of the game and code we haven't seen.

Comment: Thank you so much, so what exactly is 0xffffffff. Because to my knoweldge fffffffff is [11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111] in binary, so does x 0, just make all of those values 0, because 1 x 0 = 0? And if that is the case, wouldnt B = 0 also? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, the `0xffffffff` was a typo, I meant just `0xff`, i.e. `1111 1111` in binary.

Comment: Ok, well ff = 11111111, so 0xff = 00000000 right? Therefore, wouldn't AAAARRRRGGGGBBBB & 0xff = 00000000GGGGBBBB?, because only 8 0's?

Comment: No, the `0x` is just how hexadecimal constants are written in Java. `0xff` in an `int` is binary `00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111`.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. Can you just clarify if my understanding is right? So 0x, is just you telling Java that the following ff is hex. ff is 11111111 in binary, which is 256 in decimal. RGB has values up to 256, since you are anding it pads the 11111111 with 0's before it, thus creating 00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111, meaning that everything but blue turns to 0.

Comment: Yes, that's right, except that `0xff` is _255_, not _256_.  RGB values go 0 .. 255

Comment: Thank you, so much. This really helped. Sorry for asking so many questions.